# How to make a fragment fit in a FrameLayout in all screen sizes?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an app where I want to show few fragments in a container(Framelayout) one after other. I want my fragments to fit in the framelayout without its parts going out of the screen.

I want this:

[image: I want this:]

But Getting this:

[image: But I get this:]

Here is my code snippet:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_border_circular_rect"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/elipse1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="32dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/elipse1"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/elipse2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_elipse_filled"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="568dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/elipse2"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/elipse1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/elipse1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_elipse_blank" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> I can't share the full xml code as I have some restriction on the code. But the Root layout is also a ConstraintLayout.

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/otpVerificationTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="OTP Verification"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/btn_grey"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otpVerificationTV" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="We sent you a code"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:text="Resend OTP"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_secondary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@color/grey_secondary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
    tools:text="29 sec" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="OTP"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="262dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_circular_rect"
    android:elevation="@dimen/btn_elevation"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So is there any possible way that I can make the fragment fit on any screen size and all of it is visible inside the framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help with your **fragment.xml** file.
You didn't provided more values files means color code, string file and other. So below are some changes from your file like drawable and value related data.

Fill free to put comment if you have any question related to below views. If below code work for you then please approve this answer.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/otpVerificationTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="OTP Verification"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otpVerificationTV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="We sent you a code"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/group2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/group2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view3,textView7,textView5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/group1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/group2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="linearLayout,textView8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/group" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Resend OTP"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/group"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/group" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/group"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
        tools:text="29 sec" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="OTP"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/group1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/group1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```